# Java boolean always returns false with Scanner

Tags: java

I'm creating something to be used purely personal to generate a random "code" when needed, and using the Scanner util to confirm if the code generated is for a certain type of user, but no matter what I type, the boolean isFull returns false.

Thanks to Rohit Jain, I realise my error.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Generate {

public static int minNum = 1;
public static int maxNum = 9999999;
public static int maxLast = 9;
public static int randomGen;
public static int randomLast;
public static boolean isFull = false;
static Scanner uIn = new Scanner(System.in);

public Generate() {
    System.out.print("Is the user a Full Affiliate? Y/N \n ");
    if(uIn.hasNextLine()){
    //OLD:  if(uIn.equals("Y")){
        if(uIn.nextLine().contains("Y"){ //NEW, works.
            isFull = true;
        }else{
            isFull = false;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("Full Affiliate: " + isFull);
    System.out.println("Generating Affiliate Reference:");
    Generate.randomGen = minNum + (int) (Math.random() * ((maxNum - minNum) +1));
    Generate.randomLast = minNum + (int) (Math.random() * ((maxLast - minNum) +1));

    if(isFull){
        System.out.println("GB" + randomGen + "?" + randomLast + "*");
    }else{
        System.out.println("GB" + randomGen + "?" + randomLast);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Generate theNumber = new Generate();
}
}
```

I'm fairly new to using Java outside of Minecraft and Bukkit, so I'm thinking it's something relatively simple that I have just missed.

Comment: Re-look for what you are comparing the string `"Y"` with?

Comment: Oh wow, I just realised. I changed the uIn.equals("Y") to uIn.nextLine().contains("Y") and it works fine. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: I think it might be best to leave your code *wrong*, I could be wrong but it doesn't seem best to change the code. Perhaps @RohitJain will give an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are reading from the keyboard you should be using `uIn.nextLine()` rather than `uIn.hasNextLine()`

Just saw your edit...I would get rid of the outer if function completely and just use the inner if/else function.

Comment: Great! You generally use nextLine() when reading from the keyboard and hasNextLine() when reading from a file or string data.

Comment: Okay. I prefer learning this way (from mistakes) than reading books or following YouTube videos. It sticks more, rather than just being absorbed. Thanks again.